# How do I change this function as so it updates every 5 seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        var choice = arc4random_uniform(2)
        if (choice == 0) {

        var redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBall")
        redBall.setScale(0.5)
        redBall.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height)
        redBall.size.height = 20
        redBall.size.width = 30
        redBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: redBall.size.height / 2.75)
        redBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.addChild(redBall)

    }

    if (choice == 1) {
        var redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBall")
        redBall.setScale(0.5)
        redBall.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/5, self.size.height)
        redBall.size.height = 20
        redBall.size.width = 30
        redBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: redBall.size.height / 2.75)
        redBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.addChild(redBall)

    }

    if (choice == 2) {
        var redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBall")
        redBall.setScale(0.5)
        redBall.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width*5, self.size.height)
        redBall.size.height = 20
        redBall.size.width = 30
        redBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: redBall.size.height / 2.75)
        redBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.addChild(redBall)

    }

}
```

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21804866/790842

Comment: How should I do it in Swift, sorry I am new to swift and spritekit

Comment: Is that the update method that's supposed to be getting called once per frame?

Comment: Yes, but I want it to update on every 5seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an `SKAction` that fires every five seconds instead of using the `update` function.

```
func yourFunction (){
    //Your code
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)

    let updateAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        self.yourFunction()
    }

    let waitDuration : NSTimeInterval = 5.0
    let updateAndWaitAction = SKAction.sequence([updateAction,SKAction.waitForDuration(waitDuration)])
    let repeatForeverAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(updateAndWaitAction)
    self.runAction(repeatForeverAction)

}
```